# How do i ensure the entry function at a fixed address of bare-metal arm?

Tags: gcc, arm, ld, cortex-a8

I'm using S5PV210, a sumsung arm-cortexA8 chip. In its document, the program will start to execute at 0xd0200010. Now i succeeded run my program on it. But i still have some questions.

At first, I used link command "-Ttext 0xd02000010 -e main" , and thought that it will put the main function to address 0xd0200010. But i found that it just put .text section onto 0xd0200010. If i changed the order of function in my .c file,  even though .text section will still be put on the 0xd0200010,but main function won't be on that address, and "-e main" doesn't work at all.

So , how could i make main function to be at 0xd0200010? Can i do it just by compiler and linker command?

Comment: Typically, you write assembler that sets up the 'C' environment (like zeroing BSS data, setting a stack, etc).  Then you jump to your main routine `bl _main`.  This assembler code is in a unique section and you use a custom linker script which positions this code at the start of the image.  For *ELF* images (non-binary) you can use the `ENTRY(start)` linker to specify where initial control goes.  This doesn't work for a binary and pretty much you should use a [custom linker script](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Scripts.html).  There are various examples on the web.

Comment: Yeah,you're right...I figured it out too, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I worked it out..

elf file is used for OS platform, then entry point is defined is the header of elf file.

But for bare-metal system, it can't read the information of elf file, so it must be transformed into binary file, which doesn't contain any information about entry point.In other words, bare-metal system doesn't have concept of "entry point". So -e main option won't work for binary file.

There are many ways to place a C function on a fixed address.I just post my solution about it

1. declare main function at a user-defined section

   int main() **attribute**((section(".main")))
2. Use linker script, put the section .main on required address.

   SECTIONS
   {
       .=0x0000
       .text :
       {
         led.o (.main)
         *(.text)
       }
   ........
   }